# How to debug a "} expected error" in C#?

Tags: c#

This is a code i was working on in class. I created the code in virtual studio 2015 and it comes up with 2 `} expected` errors, one at the end of line 31, and the other one at the end of line 38.

I am new to C# and could use some help as to why my code won't run and there is a expected error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MultiConversion
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("this program can convert between units in different settings like currency, speed, and weight");
            //define vars
            double miles, kilometers, pounds, kilograms, euros, dollars;
            Int16 number, first, second, third;
            //get user input
            Console.WriteLine("please choose what you want to convert and enter the number associated with it 1speed, 2weight, 3currency.");
            number = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            if (number == 1)
            { { {   //speed conversion
                        Console.WriteLine("you have chosen to convert speed between miles and kilometers");
                        Console.WriteLine("which would you like to convert from 1miles, or 2kilometers ?");
                        first = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
                        if (first == 1)
                            Console.Write("enter miles: ");
                        miles = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                        kilometers = miles * 1.60934;

                        Console.WriteLine("your speed in kilometers per hour is" + kilometers + "per hour");
                    }
            else 
                    {
                        Console.Write("enter kilometers: ");
                        kilometers = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                        miles = kilometers * .621;

                        Console.WriteLine("your speed in miles per hour is" + miles + "per hour"); } }
            else 
                if (number == 2)
                { {  //weight conversion
                        Console.WriteLine("you have chosen to convert weight between US pounds and kilograms");
                        Console.WriteLine("which would you like to convert from 1pounds, or 2kilograms ?");
                        second = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine()); }
                    if (second == 1)
                    {
                        Console.Write("enter pounds: ");
                        pounds = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                        kilograms = pounds * 2.20462;

                        Console.WriteLine("your weight in kilograms is" + kilograms + "."); }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write("enter kilograms: ");
                        kilograms = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                        pounds = kilograms * .453592;

                        Console.WriteLine("your weight in pounds is" + pounds + "."); } }
                else
                {
                    {  //currency conversion.
                        Console.WriteLine("you have chosen to convert currency between dollars and euros using the conversion factors as of 9 - 9 - 16");
                        Console.WriteLine("which would you like to convert from 1dollars, or 2euros ?");
                        third = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
                    }
                    if (third == 1)
                    {
                        Console.Write("enter dollars");
                        dollars = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                        euros = dollars * .89;
                        Console.WriteLine("your" + dollars + "dollars is equal to " + euros + "euros."); }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write("enter euros");
                        euros = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                        dollars = euros * 1.12;
                        Console.WriteLine("your" + euros + "euros is equal to " + dollars + "dollars."); } } }
            Console.WriteLine("thank you and I hope you converted all that you need to.");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the compiler seems to be telling you exactly what's wrong. What are you having trouble understanding, _specifically_? I would suggest that you stop putting multiple braces on the same line, and follow .NET conventions by giving each brace its own line. It will be much easier to confirm matching braces and indentation that matches the actual blocking of the code that way. But at the very least, you should be able to understand what it means when the compiler tells you that it expected a brace character.

Answer (score 1):

Simple **"{"** errors.

try this,

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("this program can convert between units in different settings like currency, speed, and weight");
            //define vars
            double miles, kilometers, pounds, kilograms, euros, dollars;
            Int16 number, first, second, third;
            //get user input
            Console.WriteLine("please choose what you want to convert and enter the number associated with it 1speed, 2weight, 3currency.");
            number = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            if (number == 1)
            {   //speed conversion
                Console.WriteLine("you have chosen to convert speed between miles and kilometers");
                Console.WriteLine("which would you like to convert from 1miles, or 2kilometers ?");
                first = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
                if (first == 1)
                    Console.Write("enter miles: ");
                miles = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                kilometers = miles * 1.60934;

                Console.WriteLine("your speed in kilometers per hour is" + kilometers + "per hour");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("enter kilometers: ");
                kilometers = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                miles = kilometers * .621;

                Console.WriteLine("your speed in miles per hour is" + miles + "per hour");
            }
           if (number == 2)
            {
                //weight conversion
                Console.WriteLine("you have chosen to convert weight between US pounds and kilograms");
                Console.WriteLine("which would you like to convert from 1pounds, or 2kilograms ?");
                second = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

                if (second == 1)
                {
                    Console.Write("enter pounds: ");
                    pounds = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                    kilograms = pounds * 2.20462;

                    Console.WriteLine("your weight in kilograms is" + kilograms + ".");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("enter kilograms: ");
                    kilograms = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                    pounds = kilograms * .453592;

                    Console.WriteLine("your weight in pounds is" + pounds + ".");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                {  //currency conversion.
                    Console.WriteLine("you have chosen to convert currency between dollars and euros using the conversion factors as of 9 - 9 - 16");
                    Console.WriteLine("which would you like to convert from 1dollars, or 2euros ?");
                    third = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                if (third == 1)
                {
                    Console.Write("enter dollars");
                    dollars = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                    euros = dollars * .89;
                    Console.WriteLine("your" + dollars + "dollars is equal to " + euros + "euros.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("enter euros");
                    euros = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                    dollars = euros * 1.12;
                    Console.WriteLine("your" + euros + "euros is equal to " + dollars + "dollars.");
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("thank you and I hope you converted all that you need to.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Hope helps,